# Laravel Backpack Multi Level Data Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I wanted to implement multi level data table structure with Laravel Backpack. Please see the images for more information

- structure - https://ibb.co/i9Qfud
- initial view - https://ibb.co/h8SFSy
- trip expanded - https://ibb.co/cm027y
- city expanded - https://ibb.co/ej3N7y
- day expanded - https://ibb.co/iGffud

Is this possible with Laravel backpack ? Any references where i can find a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a Backpack functionality called [Details Row](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/advanced-features#section-details-row) that will help you achieve the first [+] button, but I'm afraid that's about it - the next ones are up to you.

You will have to:

- in your TripCrudController::setup():

  `$this->crud->enableDetailsRow(); 
  $this->crud->allowAccess('details_row'); 
  $this->crud->setDetailsRowView('details_row.expanded_trip_details_row');`
- create the blade file that outputs the table with cities, days and attractions (let's say `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/details_row/expanded_trip_details_row.blade.php`); shouldn't be very difficult, you have the current trip as `$entry` inside this file and you can drill down using Eloquent relationships into `$cities = $entry->cities`, then `$days=$city->days` etc;
- include some javascript so that subsequent [+] signs work, inside your `public/vendor/backpack/crud/js/list.js`; alternatively, you could do this with inline javascript inside the same blade file, might be cleaner that way; but remember that this blade content is put inside the details row with AJAX, so new DOM elements and events need to be registered;

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tabacitu has provided the right answer but i've observed in my case that the details_row template should be called this way :
`$this->crud->setDetailsRowView('backpack::crud.details_row.expanded_trip_details_row');`